# Does IBM Cloud Object Storage support object expiration?

Tags: object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

IBM Cloud Object Storage supports the AWS s3 API and in the AWS s3 API there is object expiration: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/

Does IBM COS support this?

Answer (score 1):

No, not at this time, but it is certainly on the roadmap. We're aware that it's an important feature for many developers.

A list of supported features can be found here: https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/about-compatibility-api

Answer (score 0):

looks like the expiration is not yet supported. I was going through the COS API reference here: https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/api-reference ... don't see anything written about expiration in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is a support feature in IBM Cloud as well as on-prem IBM COS
Cloud - [https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-expiry#:~:text=Any%20object%20that%20qualifies%20for,objects%20once%20they%20are%20deleted](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-expiry#:%7E:text=Any%20object%20that%20qualifies%20for,objects%20once%20they%20are%20deleted).

On-prem - https://www.ibm.com/docs/STXNRM_3.14.8/coss.doc/pdfs/objectExpirationFdd_bookmap.pdf